# Assign two className to child

Tags: button, reactjs, styles, classname

I have below code in my parent's component -

```
<Button className={'row1 column1'} value={'1'}/>
```

So I am sending two className to the child's component.
Then in my child component I have

```
    render() {
        var { value, className, ...other} = this.props;
        return (
          <button className={s[className]}> {value} </button>
        )
      }
}
export default withStyles(s)(Button);
```

usually I manually set `className={s.something}` and it works, but this is not. In rendered html it looks like - `<button is="null"></button>` Any idea?

Comment: I need to use it with `s.`.At the end i am exporting `export default withStyles(s)(Button);`Without `s.`, className is assign right, but css isn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed you use [react-with-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-with-style), [`withStyles`](https://github.com/apalm/react-with-style/blob/master/src/withStyle.js) will add a `styles` object to your `props`.

This object does not know any `className`s, you just need to pass those `styles` to your button as inline styles.

e.g.:

```
render() {
  var { value, className, style, ...other} = this.props;
  return (
    <button
      className={ className }
      style={ style }
    >
      { value }
    </button>
  )
}
```

EDIT:
The advantage of `withStyle` is to use inline styles. And I suppose your `s` object does not have a key `row1 column1` but rather `row1` and `column1`, so you would need to manually split the classname.

But then again, why do you want the styles in the `className`?

Comment: But in other component, i have normally `<div className={s.container}>` , then in css i have class `.container{}` and it works, i didnt need to use style={}

Comment: then why are you using `withStyle` ?

Comment: I saw it in basic react component, which was in stater kit. They have file including componentName.js, then componenetName.css and in js they have same code... `className={s.container}` and at the end they exported withStyles ... and now i want to directly assign styles to individual buttons.

Comment: then do it like in my example, leave the className as is, but assign the inline styles directly from the `styles` object you get in your props.